# Merge Consecutive cells in a Column having same values in excel

Tags: java, excel, merge, apache-poi

I have some data to be written into an excel Sheet.
i have done that part.
Now i want the consecutive cells of first column having same values to get merged.
I dont have any idea about how to merge cells by coding.
i use **apache-poi**

Below is my code.

```
 HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
      String fromAddress,toAddress;

      HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Report 1");
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
      short dateFormat = wb.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss");
HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
      HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
      cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
      cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Proposal No."));
      cell = row.createCell(1);


      cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
      cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Equipment Name"));
      cell = row.createCell(2);

      cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
      cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Quantity Ordered"));
      cell = row.createCell(3);

      cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
      cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Invoice"));
      cell = row.createCell(4);

      cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
      cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Total Invoice Value"));
      cell = row.createCell(5);

      cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
      cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Quantity Dispatched"));
      cell = row.createCell(6);
      cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
      cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Balance Quantity"));

      DispatchReports dispatchSummery=new DispatchReports();
      if (dispatchSummery != null) {
        dispatchList = dispatchSummery.dispatchSummery();
      }

        DispatchReports dispatchSummeryExtend=new DispatchReports();
          if (dispatchSummeryExtend != null) {
            dispatchListExtended = dispatchSummeryExtend.dispatchSummeryExtended();
          }


      int tempCount = 1;
```

//Data filling starts here

```
      for (int key = 0; key < dispatchList.size(); key++) {

          try {

              CmaDispatchEquipmentDetails ws = new CmaDispatchEquipmentDetails();

              int cellnum = 0;
              HSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(tempCount++);
              ws = (CmaDispatchEquipmentDetails) dispatchList.get(key);
              HSSFCell cell1 = row1.createCell(cellnum++);
              cell1.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("" + ws.getCmaId().getCmaNo()));
              cell1 = row1.createCell(cellnum++);

              cell1.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("" + ws.getEquipmentname()));
              cell1 = row1.createCell(cellnum++);


              cell1.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("" + ws.getQtyordered()));
              cell1 = row1.createCell(cellnum++);




              cell1.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("" + ws.getInvoice()));
              cell1 = row1.createCell(cellnum++);
              cell1.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("" + ws.getTotalinvoicevalue()));
              cell1 = row1.createCell(cellnum++);
              cell1.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("" + ws.getQtydispatched()));
              cell1 = row1.createCell(cellnum++);
              cell1.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("" + ws.getBalancedispatched()));


          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              tempCount--;
              continue;
          }
      }
```

Please help me merge the consecutive cells of 'proposal No.' column that have same values.